# GIT different files on remote and local repo

Tags: git, workflow

I have a file in my GIT repository that I changed through the github.com editor.

Now, I went and change this file in my local repository aswell.

What is a common workflow for solving this? I cannot pull or push now.

Comment: I think I don't understand you.  If I *do* understand correctly, then the answer is "fix whatever is stopping you from pushing/pulling", since the common workflow is to push.

Comment: I do appologize, I'm new to this.
If I try to push: "Error, to prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates are rejected... '

Comment: Ok, that means that the branch on github points to a commit that is not in the local-repository's history.  If you forced a push, the branch would start pointing to the newly pushed commit, and your change on github would be lost.  Pulling (i.e. fetch + merge), would normally work.  Did it complain about merge conflcits when you tried?

Comment: It says "Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge: README. 
Please commit your changes or stash them before you can merge. "

Comment: Then just do what it says.  Or if you don't want the changes, `reset --hard`

Comment: Well, learned some more, thanks! I need to ADD the file again and then COMMIT it, I did not know this was necessarily. Thanks for your help.

Comment: :) Doh!  I've just been training a very clever co-worker in Git, and just realised how complicated it was - even though it was the first VCS that I could actually understand.  BTW: `git commit -a` sometimes helps.  But not always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I do understand, you're saying have changes both on GitHub and Locally.   I am going to assume your local changes are committed - if not, you should either commit them or throw them away using `git reset --hard HEAD`.

In principle `git pull` should have pulled the remote changes down and merged them, but that is not working.  If git is complaining about merge conflicts then you should resolve them by hand, commit the result and then push it up.

If something stranger has happened, you can try the same approach.  First grab the remote changes in a remote-tracking branch (i.e. not in your working directory), `git pull` will probably have done this for you (use  `gitk --all` to find out).  If not, play around with `git-fetch` to try and grab more stuff).  When you have what you want in a remote tracking branch, you can do a `git merge` by hand.

(Sorry if this is not very clear, but since I don't know your exact errors, I have to guess).

Comment: With the limited info I've given you, I think this is very clear :) I understand the workflow and I'll try to figure this out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Edit file, commit changes in Github.

```
git pull ...
```

or

```
git fetch ...
```

in local repo